# Power .bind() codewars task

Tags: javascript, binding

There is a task to make a custom bind that will allow you to change the bound content an unlimited number of times. I created such a function and locally it works for me. But it doesn't pass the tests in codewars. Tell me what could be the problem.

link to this task: https://www.codewars.com/kata/5388a9d60b24c52f4c000b5f/train/javascript

Code:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function (context) {
      if (!globalThis.func) {
        globalThis.func = this;
      }
      return function (...arg) {
        globalThis.func.call(context, ...arg);
      };
    };
```

I tested this function with the following code:

```
var func = function (a) {
      console.log("Argument is:", a);
      console.log("this = ", this);
      return this.prop;
    };
    var obj1 = { prop: 1 },
      obj2 = { prop: 2 };

    func = func.bind(obj1);
    func("Arg1");

    func = func.bind(obj2);
    func("Arg2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution modify a single global variable which is supposed to be the global name of all functions that are going to use `.bind()`. This simply won't work, even in theory.

Use a `Map` (or `WeakMap`, your choice) to link each bound function to its original one.

```js
(() => { // Closure function
    const bind = Function.prototype.bind; // Original bind
    const map = new Map(); // Map<BoundFunction, Function>

    Function.prototype.bind = function(context) {
        if (!map.has(this)) { // Not found in map => not bound.
            let bound = bind.call(this, context);
            map.set(bound, this);
            return bound;
        } else {
            let unbound = map.get(this);
            return bind.call(unbound, context);
        }
    };
})();
```

Note that this does not work with functions bound before the IIFE comes in action:

```js
function foo() {
  return this.foo;
}

foo = foo.bind({ foo: 0 });

(() => { /* ... */ })();

console.log(foo()); // 0
console.log(foo.bind({ foo: -1 })()); // 0
```

Try it:

```js
(() => {
  const bind = Function.prototype.bind;
  const map = new Map();

  Function.prototype.bind = function(context) {
    if (!map.has(this)) {
      let bound = bind.call(this, context);
      map.set(bound, this);
      return bound;
    } else {
      let unbound = map.get(this);
      return bind.call(unbound, context);
    }
  };
})();

function func() {
  return this.prop;
};

console.log(func.bind(globalThis)()); // undefined

func = func.bind({ prop: 1 });
console.log(func()); // 1

func = func.bind({ prop: 2 });
console.log(func()); // 2

(() => {
  // Also works with locals
  function foo() {
    return this.foo
  }

  const foo1 = foo.bind({ foo: 3 });
  const foo2 = foo.bind({ foo: 4 });

  console.log(foo1());
  console.log(foo2());
})();
```